# subscribe multiple observable and get only one after condition match

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I have an observable of array of items and an observable of item. I want subscribe to both and get the index of observable of item from observable of array of items

i already tried switchmap, concatmap and mergemap but didn't get any result

````
selectedcategory$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedCategory));
```observable of array of items
allcategories$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCategories));

```i am working with ngrx 

I an expecting index of item
````

Answer (score 2):

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

combineLatest(
  selectedcategory$,
  allcategories$,
).pipe(
  map(([selected, categories]) => categories.findIndex(/* whatever logic you need */),
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer but i am getting this issue "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction"

Comment: @VishalArora I think you're importing `combineLatest` wrong. See that it is not imported from `rxjs/operators`, it should be `rxjs` instead. There are two separate `combineLatest` operators, one for Observable creation and another for Observable piping. One of them will soon be renamed.

Comment: @VishalArora Ritaj is right, you're probably importing wrong `combineLatest` from `'rxjs/operators'` which is different then `combineLatest` from `'rxjs'`.